# RequestTimeoutMiddleware .net8 attribute not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0

Currently I am trying to add a timeout for a specific controller in .net8.

Firstly I register the service in program.cs using

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(..);

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   //
});

// configure strongly typed settings object
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
builder.Services.AddRazorTemplating();

builder.ConfigureServices();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IErrorLogService, DatabaseErrorLogService>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISimpleFileCacheService, SimpleFileCacheService>();

builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRequestTimeouts();
```

Then in my controller I add an attribute to one of my endpoints

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [RequestTimeout(milliseconds: 1)] // 1ms for testing purposes
    public override IActionResult GetList()
    {
        HttpContext.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return Ok(MdlCountry.GetList());
    }
```

I expect it to failed. but it still gives 200 result on 800ms execution.

Comment: try adding `Thread.Sleep` in the action method body

Comment: _"on 800ms execution"_ - how do you measure it?

Comment: I think the timeout is in the wrong location.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-one-endpoint-or-page

Comment: Also please provide full setup, placing of `app.UseRequestTimeouts();` is important.

Comment: @GuruStron there is a log in the console. HTTP GET /api/Country responded 200 in 978.9826 ms

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it doesn't work. got the log HTTP GET /api/Country responded 200 in 2938.5316 ms

Comment: @GuruStron edited the program.cs for more information

Comment: @jdweng the documentation doesn't specifically show how to do it in the mvc controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in debug mode won't trigger the request timeout middleware. same as running in Release mode via visual studio.

I had to run "dotnet publish" and "dotnet applicationName.dll" via CLI and it seems to solve the problem.

reference:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/28934

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-global-default-timeout-policy

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0) that every action/handler the `CancallationToken` from `context.RequestAborted` is passed into the code.

Eg. (from that documentation page)

```
app.MapGet("/", async (HttpContext context) => {
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.RequestAborted);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Results.Content("Timeout!", "text/plain");
    }

    return Results.Content("No timeout!", "text/plain");
});
```

(For an MVC controller the `context` is available via the inherited property `HttpContext`.)

All the middleware is doing is, after the specified delay, calling `Cancel` on the `CancelationTokenSource` used to create the `CanncellationToken` referenced by `context.RequestAborted`. I have confirmed this by looking at the implementation of the middleware ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Timeouts/RequestTimeoutsMiddleware.cs)) and the helper ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Timeouts/CancellationTokenLinker.cs)): the key is taking the original `context.RequestAborted` cancellation token (used to handle cases like the connection being closed) with a second which is created with a timeout. Most of the logic is handling the various ways of setting/overriding the timeout, plus handling `OperationCanceledException` thrown by `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

TL;DR: the timeout middleware cancels the request with a `CanncelationToken`, but you need to pass that down through the code that handles the request.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What would it look like in my controller /Country then?

Comment: @PrinsAlvino `MdlCountry` needs to have a `CancellationToken` parameter on all methods (and use it when calling other methods and/or checking it itself) that take non-trivial elapsed time. (`CancellationToken` is generally easier to work with with async: generally ASP.NET Core is easier with async, and any method taking more than a few ms should be async to allow better thread utilisation).

Comment: @PrinsAlvino [Cancellation Tokens in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/) (note from the days of a `Startup` class for DI/pipeline configuration).